# Redirecionar todas as páginas para HTTPS menos uma em particular

Tags: htaccess, redirecionamento

Tenho o seguinte código no `.htaccses` para redirecionar todo o site para `HTTPS`:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://meudominio.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Entretanto gostaria de deixar uma página fora desse redirecionamento de forma a abrir em HTTP:

```
http://meudominio.com/obrigado.php
```

Como posso aplicar esta regra?

Answer (score 7):

Podes adicionar uma condição à tua regra de redirecionamento para esse endereço em particular.

Antes da linha `RewriteRule`, adicione:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/obrigado.php$
```

Desta forma, a regra de redirecionamento só é aplicada se o endereço não for parar ao `obrigado.php`.